# How to map only non-empty values?

Tags: arrays, swift

I am building an iOS app and I got an array with textfields and I want to map the text of these fields into an array.

This is what I try and it works but I only want to map a value if it is not empty. Now I get all even if the textfield is empty.

```
textFields.map{$0.text!}
```

**Update**

I solved it like this

```
textFields.filter({$0.text! != ""}).map({$0.text!})
```

Comment: This two stage produces an unnecessary intermediate array.

Answer (score 4):

The current answers both involve two passes through arrays: one to filter, and one to map.

A more efficient approach would be:

```
textFields.flatMap{ $0.text?.isEmpty == false ? $0.text! : nil }
```

The closure `{ $0.text?.isEmpty == false ? $0.text! : nil }` returns the `text` property of each element if it is non-nil (since it is an optional property) and it is not empty (empty means `== ""`).  Otherwise, it will return `nil`.

Because the flatMap method will already exclude any nil values from the final result, this guarantees that the return will be only the array of non-nil, non-empty `text` strings from the original elements, and does so with only a single pass through the array.

Answer (score 2):

```
textFields.flatMap({ $0.text }).filter({ !$0.isEmpty })
```

Or, if you want to avoid `flatMap`:

```
textFields.map({ $0.text }).filter({ !($0?.isEmpty ?? true) })
```

Answer (score 1):

This is how I would do it:

```
textFields.flatMap{
    guard let t = $0.text, !t.isEmpty else { return nil }
    return t
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As Daniel Hall answer, you should avoid 2 passes.
Before Swift 4 you need to use flatMap as he said.
But now you need to use compactMap so:

```
let array = [1, 2, nil, 4, nil, 6]
let cleanArray = array.compactMap { $0 * 1 }
```

This runs 6 times (1 for each value) but the result only have 4 values.

More info here:
https://medium.com/@abhimuralidharan/higher-order-functions-in-swift-filter-map-reduce-flatmap-1837646a63e8

Answer (score -1):

I solved it like this:

```
textFields.filter({$0.text! != ""}).map({$0.text!})
```

Answer (score -1):

For filtering the non empty values, WE Can go for FILTER in SWIFT 3.

```
filter({$0.text! != ""})
```

you don't need to go for MAP function.

This will give you only non empty (!="") values.

Thanks.